# Javascript Alert when click close button

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, When I click on close (X) button it shows error stored in variable s. Before the script was working good but now its not showing alert when i click on close button. Did i do any mistake in coding or I need to add some .js file for this to work.

```
var internalLink = false;

function pageUnload() {
    if (!internalLink && location.protocol != 'http:') {
        internalLink = true;
        var s = 'Alert Message';
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
            alert(s);
        }
        setTimeout("location.href= 'foo.com'", 100);
        return s;
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = pageUnload;
```

Or Can you provide me some other code so that when user clicks on close button. Browser will show alert stored in variable s. Note: Only show alert when click close, Not then when redirects to other link or when submit the form. it should not show any alert when click internal links.

Comment: Doesn't that only work on firefox? On other browser it should not display the alert. What are you testing in? Also... ever heard of indentation?

Comment: did you by any chance test with another browser than firefox ? also, I don't see the point of doing a redirection as as soon as the user will click on the OK button of the alert window, the brwser window will close so the rest of the javascript won't be executed.

Comment: Most browsers block alerts in the `onbeforeunload` event.  Also, you *CANNOT* redirect the user in `onbeforeunload`, once the browser is on its way to a page, you can't change it.

Comment: But its not even showing alert in firefox. Or Can you provide me some other code so that when user clicks on close button. Browser ll show error stored in variable s. 

Note: Only show alert when click close, Not then when redirects to other link or when submit the form. it should not show any alert.

Comment: This is not possible. Or at least not that I know. The onbeforeunload event is triggered by different actions and I don't think it provides any information on the action triggering it. Also, if it was working before and it's not working anymore, you would want to check all the things you changed meanwhile.

Comment: I would like,If anyone has any re-edit or solution for this script.

Comment: You are playing with dark forces here... don't upset the browser daemons... they are bad-asses. What you wanna do is not exactly simple... if you manage please post the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is very little that browsers will allow the `onbeforeunload` to do.  Heck, not all of them even support it.  I'm pretty sure Opera doesn't.

What this event is meant for is to show a confirmation box asking if you want to leave or not.  That's it.  You can't call `alert` or `confirm`, redirect the user, make an (asynchronous) AJAX call, or do a whole lot else.

What you can do is return a string.  That returned string will be shown on a browser-rendered alert asking if you want to leave or not.  Note: Firefox won't actually display your string (see bug# [588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292)).

```
var internalLink = false;

function pageUnload() {
    if (!internalLink && location.protocol != 'http:') {
        internalLink = true;
        var s = 'Alert Message';
        // You cannot alert or set location.href here

        // This will show your message in a confirm popup
        return s;
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = pageUnload;
```

So, as you can see browsers are very picky about how they handle or even trigger `onbeforeunload`.  Use it with caution.

There is no "official" way to know whether the user clicked "leave" or "stay".  The de facto way is to use the `unload` event and a `setTimeout`, but it's very hacky.

```
var internalLink = false,
    stayTimeout, stayClicked;

function pageUnload() {
    if(stayClicked){
        // Don't run this multiple times
        return;
    }

    if (!internalLink && location.protocol != 'http:') {
        internalLink = true;
        // To mark that we've ran this event once
        stayClicked = true;
        // If the user opted to stay, this will be ran
        setTimeout(stayOnPage, 1000);

        var s = 'Alert Message';
        // You cannot alert or set location.href here

        // This will show your message in a confirm popup
        return s;
    }
}

function stayOnPage(){
    // The user opted to stay, do something
    location.href= 'foo.com';

    // If you are not going to redirect, set stayClicked to false
    // otherwise leave it alone
    // stayClicked = false;
}
function leavePage(){
    // The user has chosen to leave the page, clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(stayTimeout);
}

window.onbeforeunload = pageUnload;
window.unload = leavePage;
```

A ***much*** better solution would be to assign events to the `<a>` tags, use your own `confirm` box, then do whatever.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var b in a){
    a[b].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var c = confirm('Do you want to follow this link?');

        if(c){
            // The user wants to leave, let them
            return true;
        }
        else{
            // Otherwise block the link, and do whatever
            e.preventDefault();

            location.href= 'foo.com';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But the thing is , When user clicks on close button (X) then he gets alert that "Do you really want to leave this site" then there should be two actions "Yes" and "No" If "No" then redirect to some other URL "foo.com"

Comment: @MandilSharma: I updated my answer with a very hacky solution.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is now supported in Opera 15 based on the WebKit engine.

Answer (score -1):

You have several problems in your code

1) don't hand a string to setTimeout but a function

wrong:

```
setTimeout("location.href= 'foo.com'", 100);
```

correct:

```
setTimeout(function(){location.href= 'foo.com'}, 100);
```

2) as per [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changes-2011-05-25), alert calls are allowed to be ignored in the onbeforeunload event (which apparently FF is doing).

3) Redirection is not allowed in the unload event either.

You are only allowed to return a string which is then prompted to the user (ask if they really want to leave the page). The event is cancelable, but you cannot redirect inside the event itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: I am newbie, Can you give me any solution for this script. I wanted to do as follows: "When user clicks on close button (X) then he gets alert that "Do you really want to leave this site" then there should be two actions "Yes" and "No" If "No" then redirect to some other URL "foo.com" "

Comment: @Mandil This is not possible, at least I am currently not aware of how to achieve this.

Comment: Porn sites tried to do `setTimeout(function() { window.open('foo.com')}, 100);`

Comment: I did, but nothing is happening. I think problem is somewhere else. Its not showing any error while closing.

Comment: @mplungjan I doubt that this works... It's triggered from within the unload scope and window.open by itself is susceptible for getting blocked by popupblockers.